# Change Default Path of .env files in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to setup development & production environment in ReactJs
I have created two files `.env.production & .env.development` in root

Structure looks like below

```
root
   |
   .env.production
   .env.development
```

I want to change this to

```
 root
       |
       enviroments
                  |
                  .env.production
                  .env.development
```

In simple words i want to change the default location of `.env` files in react js. How can i do that please help.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/env-cmd#using-custom-env-file-path

Comment: Thanks, Is there any way to do this from webpack, so that it can pick environment folder directly, just like it pics from the root directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution after some research, but for this we need to eject

**After eject**

change following configuration in `config/paths.js`

```
dotenv: resolveApp('.env')

to

dotenv: resolveApp('environments/.env')
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use env-cmd for that

```
npm i env-cmd
```

and update your package.json file scripts to look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "env-cmd -f ../.env  react-scripts start" // replace "../.env" with your relative path
}
```